# how to display a message box when timer elapses in c#

Tags: c#, timer

I gave my time interval as 100. when the timer elapsed the message box is displayed but my screen is flooded with message boxes. How should i stop it with one message box indicating timer elapsed.
Here's my code... Can you guide me where to give stop timer...

```
namespace timer1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Timer t = new Timer();
            t.Interval = 100;
            timer1.Enabled = true;
            timer1.Tick += new System.EventHandler(OnTimerEvent);

        }
        private void OnTimerEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            MessageBox.Show("time over");

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Please post your code so that we can see what's wrong.

Comment: Seems you already know how to show a Messagebox when a Timer elapses. Maybe you intended to ask about stopping the Timer?

Comment: Stop the timer *before* you show the message box, not after :)

Comment: Thanks for filling us in. For what it's worth I've voted to re-open the question now that you have provided the details. ChrisB's answer is what you want.

Answer (score 1):

I guess (as you don't provide code), in the Interrupt Service Routine:

```
public void YourTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      YourTimer.Stop();
      MessageBox.Show("You message...");
}
```