# Perform an action when a timer elapses

Tags: c#

I want to provide a beep sound to indicate that my timer is elapsed. Where would I put the code such that it happens when my timer has expired?

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Timer aTimer = new Timer();
        aTimer.Interval = 1000;
        // Hook up the Elapsed event for the timer. 
        aTimer.Enabled = true;
        aTimer.tick += OnTimedEvent;
    }

    private void OnTimedEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       MessageBox.Show("process");
    }
```

Comment: Are you asking how to create a system beep?  How to show a message box?  How to use a `Timer`?  Please be specific and show what you've tried and how it isn't working.

Comment: You just asked the question about the message box [two hours ago](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26123513/how-to-display-a-message-box-when-timer-elapses-in-c-sharp) and indicated in a comment that you "got it". What happened between that question and this one?

Comment: We won't just write it for you. RTFM or Google some examples, this is covered extensively. If you have a specific question about *code you've written*, that would make a better question.

Comment: I see your edit. You need to move all the code in `timer1_Tick` into your constructor and make `aTimer` an instance variable. Just google an example, this is extremely basic stuff.

Comment: @user3478065 did you get your answer?

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Media;

namespace delete
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            timer1.Enabled = true;
            timer1.Interval = 1000;
        }

        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SoundPlayer sp = new SoundPlayer();
            sp.Play();
        }
    }
}
```

don't forget to add using System.Media;